# SQL ORDER chars numerically

Tags: sql, char, type-conversion, sql-order-by, numerical

I have a column of numbers stored as chars. When I do a ORDER BY for this column  I get the following:

100
131
200
21
30
31000
etc.

How can I order these chars numerically?  Do I need to convert something or is there already an SQL command or function for this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(thecolumn AS int)
```

Comment: may want to include ISNULL(thecolumn, 0), if there are any nulls.

Comment: It won't hurt, but at least in SQL Server, the SELECT statement won't barf if some of the rows have null.

Comment: Good idea from @Russ since the sort order of NULLs is not guaranteed by SQL standard: ISNULL will force them to a specific place. I don't usually like adding per-row functions (performance killer) but you're already doing that via CAST anyway.

Comment: NULL will sort to top or bottom, but they will all sort together.  I believe whether that is the top or bottom is implementation-dependent.

Comment: if it's not unsigned, it might get sorted into the middle somewhere if you cast it to 0. Leave it null and guarantee it's at one end or the other.

Comment: Will fail if thecolumn value is not a number

Comment: What if I want to Order by based on a derived column? This seems to fail on column created like this: `substring(name from '\.(\d*)') as minor` with the error message `column minor does not exist`

Comment: Worth mentioning that in MySQL, correct function is `ORDER BY CAST(thecolumn AS SIGNED INTEGER)` or `ORDER BY CAST(thecolumn AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that MySQL doesn't accept a 2nd argument for `ISNULL` it only returns 0/1. You have to use `COALESCE(thecolumn, 0)`

Answer (score 30):

This Worked for me:

```
ORDER BY ABS(column_name)
```

Comment: Nice one. Actually this is a hidden implicit cast :) Not sure about the performance though.

Comment: This solution is problematic since it takes the absolute value of numbers. Sorting of negative values is therefore probably not what you want.

Comment: Works for MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 11):

In some situations this might be a good match:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(column_name), column_name
```

Especially if you have a column with either all digits or a mix of letters and digits but all with the same length.

Comment: I used this to sort by IP addresses

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with ordering numeric strings in a "natural sort" (if you lookup "natural sorting" on Google you'll find tons of stuff).  Essentially casting the string as int and sorting on the resulting value should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that with a char data type, you are sorting the rows as a string.

The idea to `ORDER BY CAST()` is correct, however performance of this will go down as the number of returned results increases.

If it's only numerical data in this column, the best practice would be to find a suitable numerical data type and change it.

If you really can't change the column and you find yourself having performance issues, I suggest having a sort order column which contains the value cast to an integer (will nulls converted to an appropriate value).

Index the sort order column and ideally, add a trigger to the CHAR column so that inserts or updates to the char value trigger an update to the integer value.