# Why doesn't SQL DISTINCT work with ORDER BY CAST?

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

Including DISTINCT to an SQL query that also uses `ORDER BY CAST(thecolumn AS int)` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489874/sql-order-chars-numerically) seems to remove that sorting functionality.

Any reason these cant work together?
(Using sqlite with the C api)

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
Started with -

```
sprintf(sql, "SELECT DISTINCT rowX FROM TableX Order By Cast(rowX As int) LIMIT 150 OFFSET %s;", Offset);
```

rowX is Type CHAR(5)

**NOW**:

```
sprintf(sql, "Select rowX FROM(Select Distinct rowX From TableX)t Order By Cast(rowX As int) LIMIT 150 OFFSET %s;", Offset);
```

Comment: What does your new SQL look like? Can you show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following with `sqlite`, and sorting worked fine:

```
Select Distinct thecolumn
From your_table
Order By Cast(thecolumn As int)
```

---

Have you tried putting the `DISTINCT` into a sub-query?

```
Select thecolumn
From
(
  Select Distinct thecolumn
  From your_table
) t
Order By Cast(thecolumn As int)
```

I would expect it to work that way.

---

One more way:

```
Select thecolumn
From
(
  Select Distinct Cast(thecolumn As int) As thecolumn
  From your_table
) t
Order By thecolumn
```

Comment: Does it work when you execute it directly, using `SQLite Manager` for example?

Comment: Interesting - using the manager with both of your examples gives me the same result as the basic "Select thecolumn From your_table". Strange, something must be messed up.

Comment: And it works without the `CAST` (except that it is not sorted by numbers)?

Comment: I added another way - casting in the sub-query. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

This is way super late, but the order by has to match the select list exactly so:

```
select distinct cast(column as int)
from table
order by cast(column as int)
```

Comment: this worked for my why there is no upvote.