# How to sort order by number in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am facing a problem to sort order follow the number in the column data in SQL. For example, the column data include are 100-1/1/1 ABC , 100-1/1/3 CDE, 100-1/1/2 CDE. I want to sort in order number result follow like 100-1/1/1 ABC ,100-1/1/2 CDE and 100-1/1/3 CDE.

Below is sample table data, table name called `test2`:

```html
id  |    name          | 
4     200 DAVID
1     100 JOHN
3     100-1 SHAWN
9     100-1/1 PETER
11    100-1/1/1 ALVIS
12    100-1/1/10 ROBERT
2     100-1/1/11 HENRY
13    100-1/1/3 PIRES
14    100-2 CRISTY
20    100-1/2 BILLY
32    100-1/2/1 JIOUS
```

I am using MySQL version, and write the SQL query is `SELECT * FROM test2 order by name`, but it cannot sort the number correctly.

Actually I want the expected result is like below the table:

```html
id  |    name          | 
1     100 JOHN
3     100-1 SHAWN
9     100-1/1 PETER
11    100-1/1/1 ALVIS
13    100-1/1/3 PIRES
12    100-1/1/10 ROBERT
2     100-1/1/11 HENRY
20    100-1/2 BILLY
32    100-1/2/1 JIOUS
14    100-2 CRISTY
4     200 DAVID
```

This is my real scenario for sort the name:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPMu0.png)

Hope someone can guide me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. I have edited in my question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you able help me on this question?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8+ or an earlier version?

Comment: I am using MYSQL Query Browser version 1.2.11

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is possible to sort like this question?

Comment: You need to fix your data model.  I can't/won't answer the question asked above.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I try to solve it.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Is this pattern in name column is consistent ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I can't find the solution. This pattern in name column is consistent. If you can help me, I am very thanksful.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that in your 'name' column you are storing strings, but you want to sort by numbers. This is helpful to sort digits (number strings) numerically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489874/sql-order-chars-numerically
But that solution won't work for you because you also have the dashes and name characters.
Can you restructure your table to have additional columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in using regular expression , however using basic one we could achieve it as bellow,

```
with cte as
(
select '200 DAVID' name
union all
select '100 JOHN'
union all
select '100-1 SHAWN'
union all
select '100-1/1 PETER'
union all
select '100-1/1/1 ALVIS'
union all
select '100-1/1/3 PIRES'
union all
select '100-1/1/10 ROBERT'
union all
select '100-1/1/11 HENRY'
union all
select '100-1/2 BILLY'
union all
select '100-1/2/1 JIOUS'
)
select *
  from(select t.*,cast(regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+') as unsigned) col1
                 ,cast(regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+',1,2) as unsigned) col2
                 ,cast(regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+',1,3) as unsigned) col3
                 ,cast(regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+',1,4) as unsigned) col4
  from cte t) c
order by col1,col2,col3,col4
```

First we extract the numeric required for ordering from the string using `regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+')` which matches first numeric one more character and returns the first occurrence and with `regexp_substr(name,'[0-9]+',1,2)` the second occurrence from one more numeric character match and so on...... and then use accordingly in the order by clause.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d5c70f83b5caa5047f37f2e2ac6277cd)</kbd>

**Edit:- Solution for MYSQL older versions**

```
select t.id,t.name
from
(
select t.*, cast((case when col1_col2_ref > 0 
                      then 
                        substring_index(modified_name,'-',1)
                  else 
                     modified_name
                  end) as unsigned) col1
          , cast((case when    col1_col2_ref > 0
                           and col3_ref > 0
                       then 
                          substr(modified_name,(col1_col2_ref + 1),(col3_ref - (col1_col2_ref + 1)))
                       when col1_col2_ref > 0
                       then 
                         substr(modified_name,(col1_col2_ref + 1))
                  end) as unsigned) col2
          , cast((case when    col3_ref > 0
                           and col4_ref > 0
                       then 
                         substr(modified_name,(col3_ref + 1),(col4_ref - (col3_ref + 1)))
                       when col3_ref > 0
                       then 
                         substr(modified_name,(col3_ref + 1))
                  end) as unsigned) col3
          , cast((case when col4_ref > 0
                        then 
                         substr(modified_name,(col4_ref + 1))
                   end) as unsigned) col4
  from
(
select t.*,substring_index(name,' ',1) modified_name
          ,locate('-',name,1) col1_col2_ref
          ,locate('/',name,1) col3_ref
          ,locate('/',name,locate('/',name,1)+1) col4_ref
  from test t
) t
) t
order by col1,col2,col3,col4
```

<kbd>[Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1899e00a5483e2d98053b83483830c4d)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question and add 1 picture in my question.

Comment: @Pi Network Crytocurrency Does this query in answer not giving you right results ?

Comment: Can you see my picture, cannot follow the digit to sort

Comment: Ahh.. we need to cast to integer then. updated my answer. should work now

Comment: Thanks @Sujitmohanty30 take time to help me. Maybe you must using my picture sample is better.

Comment: Is it not working you mean again ? :(. You can provide me the insert script and then I can use and check.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15sHmrdLZr6nseLFJ6mwnMmWr2AN5HwuZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa7b0c1245a399ccf76f17fc5e6d8867 and if it solves your problem accept the answer and give it a tick. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. But my error appear FUNCTION mpklang_dms.regexp_substr does not exist

Comment: I am using MYSQL Query Browser version 1.2.11. FUNCTION mpklang_dms.regexp_substr cannot using?

Comment: Got other method replace regexp_substr?

Comment: oops... not sure ...need to see and find but it would be cumbersome.

Comment: Nevermind. I also trouble in this problem. I give tick first la. Thanks.

Comment: If you have time, can help me find got other method can replace regexp_substr. Because my sql browser is old version. :(

Comment: Yes I am already looking into it. But once my office hour is over I will look in detail and update you for sure.

Comment: @Pi Network Crytocurrency This is really ugly and took a lot time and you have to consider upgrading the version and also think about data model change. this solution could trouble with performance as well. I have taken reference from internet about one user defined function to locate '`nth` occurrence of a string and without that it would be too cumbersome. here is the link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=1122731f59d141688ddd9739ef6dac00 please check

Comment: Use this link which is without any user defined function : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=6b12a4d42359cb30f27a5bfb9d0c8210

Comment: Thanks. You save my day. You are expected in SQL.

Comment: Hi, friend. I am facing based on this question sorting problem if I am inserted the new data. This is my new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63659406/user-defined-function-sorting-column-problem . If you have time, can help me to check. Thanks.

Comment: @ Pi Network Crytocurrency, I checked and this is the reason i asked if the pattern is consistent or not ? However I will check and get back to you There is already some answers .please check with those if it helps

Comment: @Sujimohanty30 Hi. I have other similar question on SQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774969/get-the-certain-column-value-follow-the-condition-in-sql-version-mysql-5-5 If you have time hope you can help me. Thanks.